# Why do my values show as NULL when pivoting table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I'm using [MySQL - Rows to Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns/9668036#9668036) and this tutorial http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-a-table-in-mysql/#comment-6128 to help me pivot a table and it's working pretty well. Starting with this:

```
mediaID q_short_name    start_time  stop_time   audio_link
ee      CVV Number       208            210     j.mp3
ee      Expiration Date  308            310     j.mp3
ff      CVV Number       124            127     k.mp3
ff      Expiration Date  166            169     k.mp3
```

The goal is this:

```
mediaID CVVNumStartT CVVNumStopT ExpDateStart_time ExpDateStop_time Aud
ee      208          210         308               310            k.mp3
ff      124          127         166               169            j.mp3
```

I got part of the way there with this code:

```
 CREATE VIEW test__extension AS (
SELECT amr_text.*, 
CASE WHEN q_short_name = 'CVV Number' THEN amr_text.start_time END AS 
CVV_Start_Time,
CASE WHEN q_short_name = 'CVV Number' THEN amr_text.stop_time END AS 
CVV_Stop_Time,
CASE WHEN q_short_name = 'Expiration Date' THEN amr_text.start_time END 
AS Expiration_Start_Time,
CASE WHEN q_short_name = 'Expiration Date' THEN amr_text.stop_time END 
AS Expiration_Stop_Time, FROM amr_text);
 CREATE VIEW test_extension_pivot AS (SELECT mediaID,
SUM(CVV_Start_Time) AS CVV_Start_Time,
SUM(CVV_Stop_Time) AS CVV_Stop_Time,
SUM(Expiration_Start_Time) AS Expiration_Start_Time,
SUM(Expiration_Stop_Time) AS Expiration_Stop_Time,
FROM test_extension GROUP BY mediaID);
```

This creates columns exactly like the goal table. But now the values for everything except the mediaIDs are rendered as NULL. My questions are, why did they get replaced by NULL, and what can I use instead of SUM to render the values of Expiration and CVV Start and Stop Time as they are in the original table?

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with some sample data and queries, please?

Comment: Unfortunately, your link seems incomplete.

Comment: should be http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9

Comment: It is... but that's not a valid fiddle.